# Is there a way to know the number of a lost debit card?

Tags: india, banking, debit-card

I am stuck in the situation where I want to know the card number of my lost debit card (lost in 2013). I have an account in the Bank of India. I checked all my entries in bank pass-books but there is no transaction where the debit card number or its last four digits have been mentioned.

I need this card number or at least the last four digits, so that the Shopper's Stop (shop) can find my old purchase receipt, because I made that purchase using this debit card and as per them if the last four digits are there, they can trace back that bill. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did the Bank of India say when you asked them "what was the number?"

Comment: @gef05 I have not been to bank, I am calling to bank help line but they are always busy/no reply. I will contact them. First I am thinking, is there a way from my internet banking transaction or bank pass book, I can get. As far as I imagines, it does not get recorded anywhere.

Comment: If you used the card online, the retailer may retain the last four digits in their system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would look at the bank website for any monthly statement that would specify the last four digits. It may also have been included in any email correspondence from the bank when the card was reported missing, or when they sent you the card originally, or if you changed the password on the card.

Many banking institutions also send a copy of any email notices as a message to your online account. Of course since you are going back 3 years+ years they may be aged out of the system.

Another source is statements from another company where the card was used to make a payment. This could be a utility bill, store purchase, or government payment. They normally include the last 4 digits so you can identify the card used to make the payment.

Comment: Boss, you are great. Generally, I do not throw any receipt. And after reading you I just went in my old stuff and found one faded shoe buying receipt, hardly visible (as heat printing fade away after some time), and by slightly tilting that receipt in light, the four-digit was visible......:)

Answer (score 4):

If you have your CC saved to your browser, you can probably look it up there, for example. in chrome, you can go into settings (chrome://settings/), scroll down, click "show advanced settings" and then under "Passwords and Forms" you can click "manage autofill settings"

Answer (score 0):

If you have online banking then simply go for profile and click on mobile changing option then type profile password and type new NUM And goes through ATM NUM then it will show your last and present card last four digits from first card of your account.